# Can I curry a function that is possibly undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have a curried function that will return undefined when run on a server (SSR), but will return an analytics package when running on the client.

```
const isServer = typeof window !== 'undefined'

getThing = () => isServer ? undefined : message => console.log(message)
```

When we access this function, we test for the existence of it, then curry events to it. The line currently reads something like this:

```
getThing() && getThing()('herpderp')
```

I find this deeply annoying. I would like to use an optional (or something like that) to evaluate for the existence of the package. Is something similar to this possible?

```
getThing()?('herpderp')
```

Comment: Yes, check the [chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) docs for accessing methods.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't update `getThing` to something like: `getThing = () => isServer ? () => undefined : message => console.log(message)`

Comment: Why not simply rewrite the function so it doesn't return `undefined` if run on a server? It could just silently discard the passed `message`.

Comment: Or `message => {}` In other words, a function which is expect to return a function should always return a function, but that function could be a no-op.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a period after the `?`:

```js
getThing()?.('herpderp')
```